# How to make telerik autocomplete text box to accept only 1 entry in c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

I am using rad autocomplete text box.I want to accept only entry after I have selected an input I have to disable so as not to accept no input but I also need to delete that input so that user can delete previous input and enter other input.i.e I need only 1 selection to be done.If a selection is made already that field has to be made read-only, If I delete the previous selection it should be again editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can `KeyPress` event and check `radAutoComplete` text length and if more than one return it.

```
private void radAutoCompleteBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (radAutoCompleteBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Also you can use this code for `textBoxes`, `comboBoxes`, etc.

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem partially, it's only disabling more than one keypress entry. What actually need is that it should not accept key entries if I have selected a value. before selecting from a suggestion I can enter values so that matching suggestions would be listed.

Comment: @ajit if i get you right, it's not possible. you can disable key entering on selected value but how user can type again?

Answer (score 0):

According to Telerik this is not possible, and that's correct, you can't stop the user "selecting" multiple entries, you can however prevent multiple entries from being "stored"

so when the user exists the auto complete field I remove all entries in the autocomplete box - except the first entered (and train the users) like so.

```
    private void stripmultientries()
    {
        // remove multi entries in the stock cat box ??? - leaver only the first
        string fulltext = radAutoCompleteBox1.Text;
        // remove everything after the first semi colon //
        int index = fulltext.IndexOf(";");
        if (index > 0)
        {
            fulltext = fulltext.Substring(0, index);
        }
        radAutoCompleteBox1.Text = fulltext;
    }
```

This method can be called when saving the form or when exiting the autocomplete control

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - I had to limit selection to only one value. That can be done checking the count of the autocomplete box items.

```
    private void radAutoCompleteBoxCWP_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent adding more than one value
        if (((Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadAutoCompleteBox)sender).Items.Count > 0)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```